# Netbeans isn't giving the proper date format

Tags: java, date

I am setting the date in gui using JDateChooser , but it is not taking the proper value . I have used the format

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

I am choosing the date from the calender provided by JDateChooser, but the month value that it is taking finally is out of bounds!!! I have no clue. There is no problem in the calender they have provided. But the value they take after processing is clearly out of bounds.

The jar used by me is : jcalender-1.4.jar

Comment: Did you try googling jdatechooser example?  I did and found a number of links that might help you.  You should also search this site.

Answer (score 1):

`mm` is minutes. You want `MM`. It's in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score -1):

Need to change `yyyy.MM.dd`on this format . may be it works